# Повтор строк в представлении mysql

Tags: sql, opencart

Всем привет, скачал модуль на опенкарт, для экспорта заказов, но он дублирует строки, подозреваю что проблема в sql запросе, но знаний разобраться не хватает. Буду благодарен если поможете.
Сам запрос

```
SELECT o.order_id, 
cgd.name as customer_group,
CONCAT(o.firstname, ' ', o.lastname) AS customer_name,
email,
telephone,
CONCAT(o.payment_firstname,
    ' ', 
    o.payment_lastname,
    ',',
    o.payment_address_1,
    ',',
    o.payment_address_2,
    ',',
    o.payment_city,
    '-',
    o.payment_postcode) AS payment_address,
CONCAT(o.shipping_firstname,
    ' ',
    o.shipping_lastname,
    ',',
    o.shipping_address_1,
    ',',
    o.shipping_address_2,
    ',',
    o.shipping_city,
    '-',
    o.shipping_postcode) AS shipping_address,
o.payment_method,
o.shipping_method,
o.total,
o.currency_code,
o.currency_value,
o.date_added,
oos.name as order_status 
FROM `oc_order` o 
LEFT JOIN oc_customer_group_description cgd 
    ON (o.customer_group_id = cgd.customer_group_id)
LEFT JOIN oc_order_status oos 
    ON (o.order_status_id = oos.order_status_id)
WHERE cgd.language_id = '1'
```

Функция

```
public function getOrdersexport($data = array()) {
 $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT o.order_id, cgd.name as customer_group, CONCAT(o.firstname, ' ', o.lastname) AS customer_name,
email, telephone, CONCAT(o.payment_firstname, ' ', o.payment_lastname,',',o.payment_address_1,',',o.payment_address_2,',',o.payment_city,'-',o.payment_postcode) AS payment_address,
CONCAT(o.shipping_firstname, ' ', o.shipping_lastname,',',o.shipping_address_1,',',o.shipping_address_2,',', o.shipping_city,'-',o.shipping_postcode) AS shipping_address,
 o.payment_method, o.shipping_method, o.total, o.currency_code,o.currency_value,
 o.date_added, oos.name as order_status
FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_group_description cgd ON (o.customer_group_id = cgd.customer_group_id)
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order_status oos ON (o.order_status_id = oos.order_status_id) WHERE cgd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'";




        if (isset($data['filter_order_status_id']) && !is_null($data['filter_order_status_id'])) {

            $sql .= " AND o.order_status_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_order_status_id'] . "'";

        } else {

            $sql .= " AND o.order_status_id > '0'";

        }



        if (!empty($data['filter_order_id'])) {

            $sql .= " AND o.order_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_order_id'] . "'";

        }



        if (!empty($data['filter_customer'])) {

            $sql .= " AND CONCAT(o.firstname, ' ', o.lastname) LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_customer']) . "%'";

        }



        if (!empty($data['filter_date_added'])) {

            $sql .= " AND DATE(o.date_added) = DATE('" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_date_added']) . "')";

        }



        if (!empty($data['filter_date_modified'])) {

            $sql .= " AND DATE(o.date_modified) = DATE('" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_date_modified']) . "')";

        }



        if (!empty($data['filter_total'])) {

            $sql .= " AND o.total = '" . (float)$data['filter_total'] . "'";

        }



        $sort_data = array(

            'o.order_id',

            'customer',

            'status',

            'o.date_added',

            'o.date_modified',

            'o.total'

        );



        if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {

            $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];

        } else {

            $sql .= " ORDER BY o.order_id";

        }



        if (isset($data['order']) && ($data['order'] == 'DESC')) {

            $sql .= " DESC";

        } else {

            $sql .= " ASC";

        }



        if (isset($data['start']) || isset($data['limit'])) {

            if ($data['start'] < 0) {

                $data['start'] = 0;

            }



            if ($data['limit'] < 1) {

                $data['limit'] = 20;

            }



            $sql .= " LIMIT " . (int)$data['start'] . "," . (int)$data['limit'];

        }

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);



        return $query->rows;

    }
```

Comment: как минимум тут LEFT JOIN  для таблицы oc_customer_group_description излишен, его можно заменить на инер джойн и сразу условие в нем прописать.

Comment: Прошу прощения, просто дублировалось из-за 2-х языков